# Cloudwatch logs filter to trigger lambda then extract values from log data

Tags: aws-lambda

Please I have got a question from the subject-line.
I want to create a AWS CloudWatch log or Event to trigger Lambda function from filter pattern then extract values from that log data as output to lambda function in python.

**Example:
Filter name: abcd
value to extract: 01234 to the lambda function.
from log data**

log Data:
abcd:01234

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify things, there is a bit of a different between AWS cloudwatch loggroups, with log streams, and AWS cloudwatch events. AWS cloudwatch events have events that can be sent from other AWS services, the aws cli and custom made. Cloudwatch logs have filters, and metric patterns that can trigger CloudWatch alarms that can be pushed into an SNS topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to capture the events from CloudWatch. The log data is in the message.  You could process here or send it on to Firehose and transform there.  Alternatively, you could send CloudWatch directly to Firehose with a subscription but I think that haas to be done with the AWS CLI.

```
import boto3
import gzip
import json
import base64

firehose = boto3.client('firehose',region_name='us-east-2')

def print_result(firehose_return):
    records_error = int(firehose_return['FailedPutCount'])
    records_sent = len(firehose_return['RequestResponses'])
    return 'Firehose sent %d records, %d error(s)' % (records_sent,records_error )

def lambda_handler(events, context):

    cw_encoded_logs_data = events['awslogs']['data']
    compressed_payload = base64.b64decode(cw_encoded_logs_data)
    cw_decoded_logs_data = gzip.decompress(compressed_payload)
    cw_all_events = json.loads(cw_decoded_logs_data)

    records = []

    for event in cw_all_events['logEvents']:
        log_event = {
            "Data": str(event['message']) + '\n'
            }
        records.insert(len(records),log_event)

        if len(records) > 499:
            firehose_return = firehose.put_record_batch(
                DeliveryStreamName = 'streamname   ',
                Records = records
            )
            print_result(firehose_return)
            records = []

    if len(records) > 0:
        firehose_return = firehose.put_record_batch(
            DeliveryStreamName = 'streamname',
            Records = records
)

    print(print_result(firehose_return))
```

Comment: Hi, Please is there anyway of using lambda sample code : def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(f'Logging Event: {event}')
    print(f"Awslog: {event['awslogs']}")
    cw_data = event['awslogs']['data']

Comment: I don't understand the comment.

Comment: Sorry - I was thinking of "cloudwatch logs stream to lambda python" , however can I export the log events to s3 for analytics?

Comment: Yes, you can use this code to go from CloudWatch to Lambda to Kinesis Firehose to s3.